# Deleting from One-to-Many relationship Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the two following models in one to many relationship:

**Category.php**

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'category_id');
}
```

And **Post.php**

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'category_id');
}
```

1. I delete thee category that has few blog post under it.
2. Open the blog post whose category is deleted
3. Gets error as the category doesn't exist anymore

**What is the best way to delete the category without causing the error ? Should I set the `category_id` of post to `null` while deleting their category ?**

Comment: First of all, in Post.php model you made wrong model relationship It should be `App\Category`

Comment: Updated. Thanks I've slipped it in a hurry.

Comment: Still your defined relationships are wrong.

Comment: Why is your relationship called `category` but it's getting a `Post`?? ...and the `post` relationship is returning multiple `Category` models?

Comment: As others have pointed out, your relationships seem to be mixed up. [The Laravel docs include examples](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) almost identical to yours, use them as a guide (they use posts and comments, you have posts and categories).  Once you have them (and your tables) set up correctly, your `post` record will only have corresponding records in the `categories` table if it has some categories.  It is then up to your code to retrieve categories for a post (`$post->categories`), and handle the case that there are none.

Answer (score 0):

Use **withDefault** for if any category doesn't exist it'll give you null.

**Category.php**

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'category_id')->withDefault();
}
```

Post.php

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id')->withDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is gonna be the late answer but I will answer for Google searches anyway.

You can handle relationship cascading on the database If you don't want any null error about deleting the models on your project. Write this code to your project table migration.

```
$table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')
      ->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
```